# container-fluid de Bootstrap me deja márgenes a los lados

Tags: html, bootstrap

Estoy usando Bootstrap en Laravel. Estoy haciendo una estructura súper simple de un `card`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Contenido
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Estoy usando `container-fluid` para ocupar el 100% de la página pero esto me deja unos márgenes a los lados de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente anexare imágenes y quiero que estas ocupen el 100% de la pantalla.

Comment: Podría proponer agregar la clase `g-0` ([no gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/gutters/#no-gutters)) al _row_, el problema es que si después querés mostrar en la misma fila más de una imagen, lucirán "pegadas".

Comment: Agregue el g-0 a los col y asi puedo controlar a quien quitarselo de manera granular, pero funciono gracias

Comment: Si quieres coloca la respuesta para marcarla como valida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la clase `px-0` de Bootstrap para eliminar el margen del `div` junto con la clase `container-fluid` resultando de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
```

Eliminando los márgenes y resultando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Contenido
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```